# Determining the probability of throwing a non-symmetrical octahedron at least 3 times

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, random-variables

I am working on a problem involving an unsymmetrical octahedron whose faces have values from 1 to 8 on them. This die is rolled until the number 5 is rolled. The probability of each face falling out is proportional to the number on that face.

My problem is to find the probability that the die will be rolled at least 3 times.

I have tried to analyse the situation by considering the probabilities associated with each face and the conditions under which the die must be rolled at least 3 times, but I have not been able to come up with a convincing method of calculating this probability.

Can anyone provide guidelines or steps for calculating the probability that the die will be rolled at least 3 times before the number 5 comes up, given the described probabilities associated with each edge?

Comment: Ignore the faces... ignore the original setting... and instead consider the identical problem where it were a coin with heads occurring with probability $\frac{5}{1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8}$ and tails occurring with the opposite probability.  Make sure you can understand why these are the same scenarios.  You ask for the probability that the first three throws will all not be heads.  This should be a standard problem type that you know how to resolve.

Comment: Let $X$ denote a random variable modeling the dice. There is a constant $C$ such that for each $i$ in $\{1,\ldots, 8\}$, $P(X=i) = Ci$.

Step 1: Determine the value of $C$.  
Step 2: Let $N$ denote a random variable modeling the rank of the first $5$. You're looking for $P(N\geq 3)$. What is the distribution of $N$ ?

Comment: "*at least 3 times before landing on the number 5*"  There may be a bit of ambiguity in that.  If you throwing a 5 on the third throw counts as success, then change what I said to "that the first two throws will both not be heads"... I had initially read it as "at least three not-5-results before eventually getting a 5-result" while Gabriel reads it as "first-5-result occurs on the third or later throw."  Both seem plausible to me, but the underlying math and analysis remains the same.

Comment: I've edited the text.